# Check attribute of html element not working

Tags: javascript

```
function hide_article() {
    var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
    if (htmlElement.getAttribute('visibility') == 'visible'){
        htmlElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        console.log("hiding");
    }
    else {
        htmlElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
        console.log("showing");
    }
};
```

This code should toggle the visibility of the article. However it always runs the "else" code block when it shouldn't. Why is this? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `'visibility'` attribute for html elements but there is `style.visibility` which you are using it already, so:

```
if (htmlElement.style.visibility != 'hidden'){
...
```

will do what you want.

Comment: Probably. But only if the `visibility` is set using the `style` attribute.

Comment: Yes there is also the `style.display` property. If it's different than 'none', there should be no problem.